# Multithreading where the each thread determines when to begin the next thread

Tags: multithreading, concurrency

I have almost no knowledge of multithreading, but a problem I am working on right now perhaps is a good opportunity to get started on learning concurrency and parallelism. I am hoping to get some pedagogical advice directed towards my specific problem.

### The Abstract Problem

In abstract, I would like to write a program with N tasks such that

1. N is predetermined.
2. Some partial information computed by the n-th task is enough for the (n+1)-th task to start. However, we don't know beforehand how much partial information is enough. The n-th task is responsible for determining that.

So what I am hoping for is to have N threads, and the important point is that the n-th thread figures out during runtime when the (n+1)-th thread can begin. Can this be achieved with multithreading? I am familiar with Java and C++. What tools/libraries should I look into to begin with?

### The Concrete Problem

The [sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is an algorithm for finding prime numbers up to a given upper limit by successively finding composite numbers as multiples of known primes. Most composite numbers have more than one prime factor and will be found multiple times. So looking for multiples of 2 and 3 in parallel can cause data race. However, the algorithm can be modified so that each composite number is found *exactly once*. Suppose we want to find all primes between 2 and K.

1. Mark 2 as prime and mark all multiples of 2 as composite. We have marked all the numbers whose smallest prime factor is 2.
2. The smallest unmarked number is 3. So 3 is the next prime number after 2. Multiply 3 with all numbers less than K/3 that are left unmarked after step 1. The products are all the numbers whose smallest prime factor is 3. Mark these numbers.
3. The smallest unmarked number is now 5. So 5 is the next prime after 2 and 3. Multiply 5 with all the numbers less than K/5 that are left unmarked after step 2 and we find all the numbers whose smallest prime factor is 5. Mark these numbers.
4. Repeat until we have reached `floor(sqrt(K))`.

Note that, for instance, step 3 can begin while step 2 is running. Early on in step 2 we find 5 as the smallest unmarked number and hence the next prime number. Therefore, once all numbers less than K/5 have been marked during step 2, we then know step 3 can begin. Step 3 will not interfere with step 1 or 2 because each composite number is found exactly once.

Comment: Yes, this can be done with multithreading. For a start, pick a language and get familiar with the multithreading facilities it provides. Note: I'm aware that this is not the info you're hoping for, but without having started anything, your question can't really present a problem or challenge, it's just a description of a task (your homework?). Please get started, then come back with actual questions.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thank you for letting me that this can be done. I will get started working on it. I encountered the modified sieve of Eratosthenes and realized that a large part of it is parallel in structure. I only have a naive idea of what multithreading does. So I was hoping to be sure whether multithreading is relevant at all before committing to it.